# redirecting to authentication-failure-url even details are correct, in spring security unix

Tags: mysql, unix, spring-security

Hi following are my springsecurity.xml

```
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <!--<user-service>-->
            <!--<user name="admin" password="secret" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />-->
            <!--<user name="user1" password="1111" authorities="ROLE_USER" />-->
        <!--</user-service>-->
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password, 'true' as enabled from USER_DETAILS where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select USER_DETAILS.username , USER_AUTH.AUTHORITY as authorities from USER_DETAILS,USER_AUTH
                  where USER_DETAILS.username = ? AND USER_DETAILS.username=USER_AUTH.USERNAME "/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

and following are the details of data source

```
    login.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    login.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBNAME?autoReconnect=true
    login.username=xxxxxxxx
    login.password=xxxxxxxx

   ##c3p0 configurations
   login.c3p0.acquireIncrement=5
    login.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod=6000
   login.c3p0.maxPoolSize=30
   login.c3p0.maxStatements=0
   login.c3p0.minPoolSize=10
   login.c3p0.initialPoolSize=10
    login.c3p0.maxIdleTime=0
   login.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=3
   login.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=20000
   login.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure=false
```

the same is working in my development machine,and when it is moved to Production Login machanism is failing.
some time back it is giving "APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!". error. 
Now it is simply redirecting to error page even user details are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with MYSQL installation.

in my authentication manager---->users-by-username-query,

table names are in capital letters, in my dev machine mysql accepting table name without seeing case, but in production same is failing.

IN linux by default MYSQL table names are case sensitive.
So please check if you are working with windows as DEV and Production machine as LINUX.